# Passing C# char array to C++ not same as byte array

Tags: c#, c++, arrays

In C++,

```
__declspec(dllexport)
    void charArrayTest(void * ptr)
{
    char*c = (char*)ptr;
    c[0] = 97;
    c[1] = 0;
    c[2] = 97;
    c[3] = 0;
}
```

this works fine for C# byte array:

```
[DllImport("KutuphaneCL", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern void charArrayTest(byte[] arr);


byte[] tst = new byte[20];
charArrayTest(tst);
Console.WriteLine(tst[0]);
Console.WriteLine(tst[1]);
Console.WriteLine(tst[2]);
Console.WriteLine(tst[3]);
Console.WriteLine(tst[4]);
Console.WriteLine(tst[5]);
```

output:

97
0
97
0
0
0

but when I try char array from C# side,

```
[DllImport("KutuphaneCL", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern void charArrayTest(char[] arr);


//simpleCharSingleGPU();
char[] tst = new char[20];
charArrayTest(tst);
Console.WriteLine((int)tst[0]);
Console.WriteLine((int)tst[1]);
Console.WriteLine((int)tst[2]);
Console.WriteLine((int)tst[3]);
Console.WriteLine((int)tst[4]);
Console.WriteLine((int)tst[5]);
```

it outputs zeroes. I expected non-zero values since lower or higher parts of each char is being altered in C++(unless array of char is not passed as a primitive array)

Why can't C# pass array of chars just same as array of bytes (I'm aware of char being 2 byte in memory but how can this be related to the case "I can't change it in C++"?)

Using Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition with latest updates. Both sides are compiled for x64.

Also there are weird things like `Marshal.SizeOf(tst[0].GetType())` returns "1" while `sizeof(char)` returns "2" in C#(unsafe context).

Comment: As you said, in C# a `char` is an *unicode* character (16 bits). I believe the marshaling is not straightforward in this case. You'll better use different types for your purpose (`string`, `StringBuilder` or `byte[]`).

Comment: I was going to use this for computing arrays in OpenCL. There is cl_half type same as C#'s char. I cannot get its pointer to copy it to GPU. Actually I need pointer of char array to start copying all bytes of it in one command of opencl.

Comment: Try adding this to the DllImportAttribute: `CharSet = CharSet.Ansi`

Comment: @cubrr nice but didn't work

Comment: @cubrr CharSet.Unicode worked

Comment: Ah, of course, with CharSet.Ansi, it will probably copy the data to an ASCII-encoded string, which is then passed to your function.

Comment: @cubrr will CharSet.Unicode always work regardless of the text inside char array? I accept your answer

Comment: I do not know and I cannot make any guarantees. It would be safer to pass a `StringBuilder` or byte array. Check out the "Passing Strings" section of this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446536.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change string to byte array in this way

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(somestring);
```

and pass it to c++ function

Comment: So do you mean there is no way without copying?

Comment: I do not know because in c # char is two bytes and c ++ one byte, somewhere there must be a conversion.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik you could always save the values as a byte

Comment: Passing it to C++ functions as `char[]` does not work, but byte works float works double works, every other primitive works. Maybe char is not a primitive?

Comment: char is primitive but different in c++ and c#. c++ natively supports ANSI encoding which is 8 bit, so char has 8 bits. c# natively supports UTF-16 so char has 16 bits. That is reason.

Comment: so as @cubrr says, only CharSet.Unicode makes it 2 bytes when converting, because it natively supports 16 bit representation.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik I would say it's more accurate to say that C++ doesn't have a concept of what a `char` really is in the same sense that C# does. The C++ `char` directly maps size wise to `byte` in C#, in C++ the type that most closely matches a C# `char` is `char16_t` which is designed for use with UTF-16.